# Error while getting double value from user input

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, error-handling, double

So to start off, I am supposed to make a GUI Application. The program is done but I have 2 very annoying mistakes that I dont know how to fix.

The first problem is comestic.

This is how the program is supposed to look like:

[image: Required look]

This is how my program is looking like:

[image: Current look]

As you guys can see, my TextFields and buttons are not lining up like they should be and the window is also too big. I have 4 Grid Panes going on right now, I have all the Padding and Vgap/HGap done like my professor asked for but its just not working out.

I will post some pictures of my constructors as well as some pictures of my GridPanes at the end of the post.

**Secondly,**

Im only using two Double input number. Those are Atomic Weight 1 and 2, both are inputs filled in by the user and they should both the Double values, throw them in the formula and return a Double.

Everything works fine up until I put a double value on my second Atomic Weight TextField. The program crashes and gives me a huge error.

What I dont understand is I coded the lines for both (Double)Atomic Weights the same way but only the first TextField will take a Double value without crashing. I will put some codes down here as well.

To sum it up:

**1. How do I change my Application's dimension so it looks like the one from the first picture**

**2. How can I fix the problem when everytime I put a Double value (1.01) in my SECOND Atomic Weight Text Field the program crashes?**

Code:

Label Method:

```
private Label makeLabel (String text) {
    Label result = new Label(text);
    result.setFont(new Font(FONT_SIZE));
    return result;        
}
```

Text Field Method:

```
private TextField makeTextField (String text) {
    TextField result = new TextField(text);
    result.setFont(new Font(FONT_SIZE));
    result.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    result.setPrefWidth(100);
    return result;
}
```

Button Method:

```
private Button makeButton (String text) {
    Button result = new Button(text);
    result.setFont(new Font(FONT_SIZE));
    result.setPrefWidth(120);
    result.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    return result;
}
```

Grids:

```
//Create 1st GridPane with Author and Course information
    GridPane topGrid = new GridPane();
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(topGrid);

    //1st GridPane Label locations
    topGrid.add(authorLabel, 0, 0);
    topGrid.add(courseLabel, 0, 1);

    //1st GridPane Paddings
    gridPadding = new Insets(10, 50, 10, 50);
    topGrid.setPadding(gridPadding);
    topGrid.setHgap(10);
    topGrid.setVgap(10);

    //1st GridPane Scene display
    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Molecular Weight Calculator");
    primaryStage.show();


    //Create 2nd GridPane w/ Title/Data Entry
    GridPane upMidGrid = new GridPane();
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(upMidGrid);

    //2nd GridPane Label locations
    upMidGrid.add(atSymbolLabel, 0, 2);
    upMidGrid.add(atWeightLabel, 1, 2);
    upMidGrid.add(atCountLabel, 2, 2);

    //2nd GridPane TextFields locations
    upMidGrid.add(atSymbolTF1, 0, 3);
    upMidGrid.add(atSymbolTF2, 0, 4);
    upMidGrid.add(atWeightTF1, 1, 3);
    upMidGrid.add(atWeightTF2, 1, 4);
    upMidGrid.add(atCountTF1, 2, 3);
    upMidGrid.add(atCountTF2, 2, 4);

    //2nd GridPane Paddings
    gridPadding2 = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    upMidGrid.setPadding(gridPadding2);
    upMidGrid.setHgap(20);
    upMidGrid.setVgap(5);

    //2nd GridPane Scene display
    upMidGrid.getChildren().add(topGrid);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
    primaryStage.show();


    //Create 3rd GridPane w/ Title/Output
    GridPane lowMidGrid = new GridPane ();
    Scene scene3 = new Scene(lowMidGrid);

    //3rd GridPane Label locations
    lowMidGrid.add(molFolLabel, 0, 5);
    lowMidGrid.add(molWeiLabel, 0, 6);

    //3rd GridPane TextField locations
    lowMidGrid.add(outputFolTF, 1, 5);
    lowMidGrid.add(outputWeiTF, 1, 6);

    //3rd GridPane Paddings
    lowMidGrid.setPadding(gridPadding2);
    lowMidGrid.setHgap(20);
    lowMidGrid.setVgap(5);

    //3rd GridPane Scene display
    lowMidGrid.getChildren().add(upMidGrid);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene3);
    primaryStage.show();


    //Create 4th GridPane with buttons
    GridPane bottomGrid = new GridPane();
    Scene scene4 = new Scene(bottomGrid);

    //4th GridPane Button locations
    bottomGrid.add(calcButton, 0, 7);
    bottomGrid.add(quitButton, 1, 7);

    //4th GridPane Paddings
    bottomGrid.setPadding(gridPadding2);
    bottomGrid.setHgap(20);
    bottomGrid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    //4th GridPane Scene display
    bottomGrid.getChildren().add(lowMidGrid);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene4);
    primaryStage.show();


}
```

If more code is required for the first issue, please let me know!

Code for the second issue:

Calculate Button Activation:

```
        //Activate the buttons

    //Calculate Button
    calcButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        formula(atSymbolTF1, atCountTF1, atSymbolTF2, atCountTF2, outputFolTF);
        weight(atWeightTF1, atCountTF1, atWeightTF2, atCountTF2, outputWeiTF);
    });
```

Molecular Weight Method:

```
/**
 * Formula to get the Molecular Weight
 * 
 * @param atWeightTF1 TextField containing the first symbol
 * @param atWeightTF2 TextField containing the second symbol
 * @param atCountTF1 TextField containing the first atomic count
 * @param atCountTF2 TextField containing the result (formula)
 * @param outputWeiTF TextField containing the second atomic count
 */
private void weight (
    TextField atWeightTF1,
    TextField atWeightTF2,
    TextField atCountTF1,
    TextField atCountTF2,
    TextField outputWeiTF

) {

    //Get first Double for first weight
    double weight1 = Double.parseDouble(atWeightTF1.getText());

    //Get first int for first Atomic Count
    int count1 = Integer.parseInt(atCountTF1.getText());

    //Get second Double for second weight
    double weight2 = Double.parseDouble(atWeightTF2.getText());

    //Get second int for second Atomic Count
    double count2 = Double.parseDouble(atCountTF2.getText());

    //Get the Molecular Weight
    double molWei = weight1 * count1 + weight2 * count2;

    //Store Molecular Weight 
    outputWeiTF.setText(Double.toString(molWei));

}
```

[image: Picture of all variables being declared and commands being created]

[image: Picture of the error I get when I input double values on second text field]

I know this is all very demanding and I am very sorry about that! It's a lot of code to analyze but I dont think the issues are that hard to solve :)

Let me know if I can send any extra code.

Have a great night!

Comment: I have fixed a few typos and inline the image. I also changed a few lines with caps to something a little less loud. A few further suggestions: Don't post code or exceptions as images. People won't be able to copy and play around with them making it less likely for someone to help you.

Comment: One last thing: If you have two problems that are so seperate from each other (one layout, one error), please post them as seperate questions. That way people who only know the answer to one of your problems can still answer and people who might have the same as one of your problems won't have to search through everything to find the bit that answers their part of the issue. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your second problem is that you add the textfields to the `weight()` method call in the wrong order.

Your method header is

```
private void weight (TextField atWeightTF1, TextField atWeightTF2, TextField atCountTF1, TextField atCountTF2, TextField outputWeiTF)
```

but you call it with

```
weight(atWeightTF1, atCountTF1, atWeightTF2, atCountTF2, outputWeiTF);
```

The order of weight and count fields does not match up.
Correct would be therefore:

```
weight(atWeightTF1, atWeightTF2, atCountTF1, atCountTF2, outputWeiTF);
```

As for your first problem, I can't reproduce that, since I won't type all that screenshot code, but I guess that you add the lowMidGrid wrong to it's parent, or need to change it's column range, so the grid fits in multiple cells.